# How to create a composite index in Firestore with document Id

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm using firebase cloud firestore with swift (but this is a general question with firestore), and I want to sort through some documents using a query, something like

```
fetchQ.whereField(fieldName, isGreaterThan: startingValue)
```

But then I want to guarantee some kind of order if the field has the same value, and it stands to reason that the document id is good for this, so I add

```
.order(by: FieldPath.documentID(), descending: false)
```

But now I get the error in the console where I have to paste the url in order to create a composite index. I do that, except it's only for the single index "fieldName", leaving out the document id, so obviously I get an error for trying to create a composite index with a single field. I also tried it with two fields plus the document id, and sure enough the url generates a composite index for the two fields but leaving out the document id.

The composite indexing page in the firebase console also does not have an option to create a composite index involving the document id.

So it would seem to me that maybe using document id for sorting is not the intended practice? Should I create a unique id for each document for sorting purposes or if I can use document id for ordering how should I do it?

Comment: Sorting by document id is an unusual practice, as their "random" in some sense (unless you create them to be timestamp-based). The order function is usually referring to a field within the documents being queries (not the id of the documents themselves). My suggested solution would be to have a timestamp field and order by that, or simply order by any other field within the documents.

Comment: Well... in this case I don't care about the randomness of the id, just that the order is guaranteed. I do use timestamps but it's possible to have fields created at the same time in this particular case. I don't have an issue with creating another field for sorting, I suspect that's what I might have to do anyway. But I was just wondering if id can be used.

Comment: From the docs: "By default, a query retrieves all documents that satisfy the query in ascending order by document ID" (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#swift). So the behaviour you want to to achieve is what you get out of the box.

Comment: @PeterFriese Yes you're right. I read documentation by skipping sentences and I overthink. If you want to make it a proper answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs: "By default, a query retrieves all documents that satisfy the query in ascending order by document ID" (firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/…). So the behaviour you want to to achieve is what you get out of the box.